# How do you initialize a 2d array of one type with the dimensions of a 2d array of another type

Tags: java, android-studio, multidimensional-array

Nooby question I know but I Have an Integer[][] array initialized to Integer[X][Y] and a Button[][] array,
How do I also initialize the Button array to also be Button[X][Y]. I tried using a double for loop but I feel like I am missing an easier way.

Comment: Two nested for loops are ok

Answer (score 0):

```
Button buttons[][] = {
                {findViewById(R.id.button00), findViewById(R.id.button01)},
                {findViewById(R.id.button10), findViewById(R.id.button11)}
        };
```

This code works good for me